# Django Template DoesNotExist Error

Tags: python, django

My code:

setting.py

```
    TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates').replace('\\', '/'),
)

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from core import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',views.home,name='home'),

    )
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    return render_to_response('templates/home.html')
```

But I am Getting Error something like:

**TemplateDoesNotExist at /**

templates/home.html

Can someone point me what I am missing

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean just "home.html"?

Comment: So you have a `templates/templates/home.html` template then?

Comment: I tried home.html also

Comment: Try this: `templates/app_name/home.html` and just `"home.html"`

Comment: I am guessing that you have the app folder and the templates folder at the same level.  If so, change 'templates' to "../templates" in your call to os.path.join.

Answer (score 1):

Since your TEMPLATE_DIR is already pointing to /templates, could you try:

```
def home(request):
    return render_to_response('home.html')
```